# Cannot Create migrations for EF Core Sql lite in UWP app

Tags: sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I am using VS 2015 below is a copy of my project.json file.  The project is a UWP app targeting 10.0 build 14393.

I've taken over this app and it has previous migrations.

When I try to run the Add-Migration command from the nuget Package manager I am getting "The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'XXX'."

This project is the same project that has the project.json file below.  My entities are not in a separate class library.  I can't seem to figure out how these migration scripts got created and how to create new ones going forward.

[image: project.json]

Comment: Does your solution have multiple projects? Have you selected the right project to target?

Comment: Yes it does.  My project target is the same project as the Universal Windows App.  http://imgur.com/a/2cxWo

Comment: In the package console, change the dropdown above to target the project that contains the entity framework reference.

Comment: The migration should take place in the uwp application i am targeting.  I am using EF core since EF 6 in not compatible with uap10.0.  The context is setup in that project.  This is the guide I believe was followed:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

Comment: I do have entityframe work installed in a different project.  Is it possible it is colliding and not finding the ef core dependency?

Comment: What is your setup in the configuration manager?

Comment: Just use the sqlite-net wrapper, it actuatlly works, no ceremony needed https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.  For those that may still have this issue I discovered it was actually due to the fact that I had a second project that had a reference to EF6 in it.  Because of this the Package Manager was conflicting on the shared EF6 and EF Core commands.  This worked fine once I prefixed my commands.

## Invokes the EF Core command

PS> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration

## Invokes the EF 6 command

PS> EntityFramework\Add-Migration

Referenced in this article but was something I overlooked:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: That's great. Your answer will be helpful to other developers :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the same environment to test the "Add-Migration" command. There's no problem. It worked well. See the following screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Please check the default project in your Package Manager Console to see if it's your current project.

You can see the following screentshot, my project's name is "SqliteCore", so the default project in Package Manager Console is the same.

[image]